# Express js routes - overlapping params

Tags: javascript, express, url-routing

I have a route called `date` where I list all posts of the entered date.
ie: `/date/26-12-2015`

Then I implemented rudimentary paging so I don't show all the data at once. ie: `/date/26-12-2015/2`  for page two

Now this all works, but I wanted to add a route which counts all articles of the day with `/date/26-12-2015/count` but the route think it's a page parameter.

What is the best option? Do I filter the page param if it contains 'count' or what is the preferred way of routing this?

This is my code:

```
router.get('/:date/:page', function(req, res){

    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('collectionXYZ');

    collection.find([...], function(e, docs){
        res.json(docs);
    });
});

// this gets skipped  (because it thinks it's a parameter to the page route?)
router.get('/:date/count', function(req, res){
    var dateStart = new Date(req.params.date);

    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('collectionXYZ');

    collection.count([...], function(e, docs){
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

Comment: just place `/:date/count` route before the other one.

Comment: well that was quick, and you're right. marking as duplicate - sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put static routes at the top, `/:id` will match with everything.